HTML to PDF - Aspose - Flattened - Still PDF is editable in browsers
Converting HTML stream to PDF using Aspose -  and setting FormFieldBehaviour = FormFieldBehaviour.Flattened
till generated PDF is editable when opened in browsers.
var saveOptions = new PdfSaveOptions()
{
    PageSetup =
    {
        PageLayoutOptions = PageLayoutOptions.FitToWidestContentWidth,
        AnyPage = new Page(new Margin(10, 10, 10, 10)),
    },
    Css = { MediaType = MediaType.Screen },

    // Flatten all form fields
    FormFieldBehaviour = FormFieldBehaviour.Flattened,
};

Should set PDF as non-editable.

Is it possible that you can share the sample HTML as well? OR you can please create a post in our dedicated support forum which is the right and recommended place to discuss such issues. We will be addressing it accordingly. This is Asad and I work as Developer Evangelist at Aspose.
